# P2 Update for Eclipse RCP Application fails with missing dependency error

Tags: eclipse, rcp

The p2 update process fails with the following error:

```
!ENTRY org.apache.log4j 4 0 
!MESSAGE com.my.myclass  - Software being installed: UI Application 10.2.16.202309270758 (com.my.app.update.feature.group 10.2.16.202309270758)
Missing requirement: UI Application 10.2.16.202309270758 (com.my.app.update.feature.group 10.2.16.202309270758) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.my.app.components.feature.feature.group [10.0.0.qualifier,10.0.0.qualifier]' but it could not be found
```

We have defined a update feature project and also an update site. Not sure why the dependency is having .qualifier. Looked for all entries and the update feature project has a similar dependency com.my.app.components.feature 10.0.0.qualifier in the feature.xml, but at runtime it is not resolved.